# Pushing to clients from a web service

Tags: c#, web-services, jakarta-ee

Good afternoon,

I am looking to have a web service that deals other web services (and databases) to collect data that is then stored within its own database. This is all quite straight-forward as I can regularly poll these to gather changes.

now communicating with the clients is the problem here. The web service can be created in any language (although C# or Java are the main candidates). But they will need to push data to clients written in Silverlight and Android (and others to be decided).

Polling is of course possible but on mobile devices we don't want constant polling, and besides in as real time as possible comms is important here

If this was totally in C# then I would imagine I could use duplex channels but I need something that is more general in order to push. So the question is what is available to do this? Also it needs to be free in an ideal world.

Seems a simple thing, a way to push from a web service toa  client but I suspect it is far from simple (but maybe I can be proved wrong, I hope!)

Comment: Android - http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/07/android-push-notifications-tutorial/                                                  Windows Phone - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402537(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: I would say Web Service achitecture is not intended for push services.

Comment: @EmanueleGreco This may well be the case, but if so what alternative options are there?

Comment: Web Service is cross-platform but strongly tied to the concept of Request and Response; implementing push you have to follow device-specific services, look at @L7ColWinters comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no platform independent way to do what I want and so the way forward has been decided as the following for now:

Silverlight clients will use a polling mechanism to get the data and Android clients will use XMPP to get the messages.

This does have disadvantages in the polling aspect however there are no readily available free libraries to do it that work with Silverlight but in the future we will move to using XMPP throughout when we have the cash